# Negating statements with quantifiers in them

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

First statement,

**∀ odd integers *n*, ∃ an integer *k* such that *n* = 2k + 1**

Second statement,

**∃ *m* ∈ ℝ such that ∀ *n* ∈ ℝ, *m* · *n* = *n***

Before the negation, I'd like to ask tips on how to translate this into English, removing the symbols and variables.

This is what I think.

For the first one:
*For all of the odd integers, there exists an integer such that the odd integer is equal to two times the integer plus one.*

Second one:
*There exists at least one number in the set of real numbers such that for each number in the set of real numbers, the first number times the second number is equal to the first.*

Any suggestions?

For the negation..well any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "... *removing the symbols and variables* ..." In my opinion, $m\cdot n = n$ is much easier to read than "the first number times the second number equals the second number."

Comment: Yep. I think the way NotALoner described them, it flows better. I was foolish to think otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

$a)$: For any odd integer $n$, there is some integer $k$ such that: $n = 2k+1$,

$b)$: There is a real number $m$ such that for any real number $n$: $m\times n = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Dual Negation: $$\neg \forall x\in S : P(x) \;\iff\; \exists x \in S:\neg P(x)
\\\neg \exists x\in S : P(x) \;\iff\; \forall x \in S:\neg P(x)$$

---

When in doubt, take it one step at a time.

So "**not** $\forall$ odd integers n, $\exists$ integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$"

Becomes "$\exists$ odd integers n, **not** $\exists$ integer $k$, such that $n=2k+1$"

Then "$\exists$ odd integers n, $\forall$ integer $k$, such that **not** $n=2k+1$"

Finally "$\exists$ odd integers n, $\forall$ integer $k$, such that $n\neq 2k+1$"

---

Can you complete the other question now?

Comment: ∀  m ∈ ℝ such that ∃ n ∈ ℝ, m*n != n

I think this is right. I see that whenever you negate one quantifier, it becomes the other quantifier. And then your statement, let's call it P(n,m), must be false(or something like that).

Comment: @SmugglerofLobsters . Basically yes.  As you 'move' the negation trough the quantifiers, they 'flip' into their duals, then you negate the predicate statement.  More or less.